# is it possible to use ActiveX ocx in a "Win32 Dynamic-Link Library" visual C++ project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, activex, ocx

is it possible to use ActiveX ocx in a "Win32 Dynamic-Link Library" visual C++ project?
how do I do the event handling?
I found all example with the container is a CDialog

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You handle the events the same as you do with other ActiveX uses; you register with the control to receive them.

Comment: thanks a lot, is there a sample code? I cannot make it work